# 2nd scale with ticks being a function of first ticks at same position in python/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib in Python and want to use the same plot but with several different axes that are all functions of the first one, but that do not linearly depend on the first y value.

As an example, let's assume a plot that shows a simple line y=x.
Now I have a random function like f(y)=5y^2 + 2.

My ideal output graph should now still be a line, but the equidistant ticks should not be y=1, 2, 3, 4, but f(y)=7, 22, 47, 82, so that I can overlay the two graphs with 2 different axes.

Is this even possible, as the distance between the ticks is not even nor can it be expressed in a log plot? Therefore I simply want to put a function on each tick value, without changing the graph nor the ticks' positions.

In a graphics program this would be straightforward, by simply using the same plot and manually rewriting each tick.

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fp2vrFvlz-9xdJPmqdQjyMQK7gzPX24G/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2xQy.png)

Thank you in advance! The example code is not really helpful, as it is just the standard matplotlib code but the most important scaling part is missing.
I know that I can set the ticks manually with yticks, but this does not solve the scaling problem and all ticks would appear very close together.

```
    plt.plot(["time_max_axis"], ["position_max_axis"])
    plt.xlabel("Time (ms)")
    plt.ylabel("Max position (mm)")
    plt.ylim(0, z0_mm)
    plt.show()

    plt.plot(["time_max_axis"], ["frequency_axis"])
    plt.xlabel("Oscillation frequency (kHz)")
    plt.ylabel("Max position (mm)")
    plt.ylim(fion_kHz, fion_kHz * (1 + (f_shift4 + f_shift6) / 100))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From what I understand it can be easily done with a ghost axes. But I will need to know how exactly your expected output look like. Upload an image (or link to an image) of the plot you want to have.

Comment: As a new member, I cannot upload images, which makes it more complicated to understand.

I rephrased the original question!

Comment: You can post link to an image. I read your edit, still don't understand. I can't imagine how the axes should be placed. Function on each tick values? What does it suppose to mean? Moreover, provide your attempt.

Comment: I'll answer this one but please bear in mind, that SO is not a site for free coding service. You have to try to solve it first. Share your attempt, show your effort and let the community helps you with your actual problem. The piece of code that you shared in your question has nothing to do at all with your question.

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot. I was rather expecting to hear just the required methods to look up!

I will have to dig deeper into the lines to understand them fully, but as I see it, you created 2 plots on top of each other in which one of them does not have any data and everything is made invisible except the ticks. Although I don't see through which line mpl knows where to place the equidistant ticks on the nonlinear scale.

Comment: I explained further in the comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator)

x = np.arange(50)
y = x/10 + np.random.rand(50)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1, 20]})
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

axs[1].plot(x, y)
axs[1].plot(x, 2*y)
axs[1].plot(x, 3*y)
axs[1].grid()
axs[1].set_ylim(0)
axs[1].set_xlim(0)
axs[1].set_ylabel('max displacement $z_{max}$ (mm)')

ymin, ymax = axs[1].get_ylim()
majorlocator = ymax // 8 # 8 horizontal grid lines
ytickloc = np.arange(0, int(ymax), majorlocator)
axs[1].yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(majorlocator))

ax1 = axs[1].twinx() # ghost axis of axs[1]
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax1.set_yticks([ymin, ymax])
ax1.set_yticklabels(['', f'$z_0$ = {round(ymax,2)}'])

axs[0].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axs[0].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axs[0].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
axs[0].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
axs[0].set_xticks([])
axs[0].set_yticks(ytickloc)
ytick2 = 5 * ytickloc**2 + 2 # f = 5y^2 + 2
ytick2 = list(ytick2)
ymin2 = ytick2[0]
ytick2[0] = ''
axs[0].set_yticklabels(ytick2)
axs[0].set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
axs[0].set_ylim(0)
axs[0].set_ylabel('Oscillation frequency $f_{osc}$ (kHz)')

ymax2 = 5 * ymax**2 + 2 # f = 5y^2 + 2
ax0 = axs[0].twinx() # ghost axis of axs[0]
ax0.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax0.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax0.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax0.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax0.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax0.set_yticks([ymin, ymax])
ax0.set_yticklabels([f'$\\bf{{f_{{ion}}}} = {round(ymin2, 2)}$', f'$f_{{max}}$ = {round(ymax2,2)}'])

plt.tight_layout()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: ``yticklabels`` is simply text, it has nothing to do with the location of the ``yticks`` itself. I can as well as put ``'a', 'b', 'c'`` there instead of (non-linear) scale. ``ytickloc`` itself is determined by the main axis (``axs[1]``) in this line of code: ``ytickloc = np.arange(0, int(ymax), majorlocator)``

Comment: Thank you a lot, this helps and teaches really a lot! I think the plt commands that I built upon are from a very old version. Now it works after finding the proper imports and minor adjustment of:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

axs[1].set_ylim(0, z0_mm)

for index, tick in enumerate(ytick2):
            ytick2[index] = float("{:.2f}".format(tick))

Comment: I see, so the ghost axis has exactly the same relative tick positions but the values have been chosen manually.

Comment: Glad to help. The plt command is not *old*, it's just *different*. It works for a casual plotting one single axis (which is not the case here). And yes, my bad, I have my whole imports somewhere else and don't bother looking for them.

Comment: What do you mean with minor adjustment? Was my code not working as it is?

Comment: It was working after finding the correct import statements to use, this was not completely self-explanatory to me. The minor adjustment was just to make the scaling relative to the constant z0, in your code it is relative to the largest datapoint. But that is already the application of the code. Thank you very much for the help!